# populating 2D numpy array based on condition - python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 2D numpy arrays: Y and CN.
CN are all zeros at the beginning. I want to fill some of CN elements with values that depend on a condition related to Y values. The filling is using this line of code:

```
CN = np.where(Y.dot(Y.T) == np.square(Y) , 1 , 2)
```

For example:

```
Y =  [[1]
      [2]]
CN = 
 [[0 0]
 [0 0]]
```

#CN shape is (Y.shape[0],Y.shape[0])

After applying the line of code above I get:

```
CN = 
 [[1 2]
 [2 1]]
```

What I want is that CN array only gets populated - using the above line of code - when Y value == 1.
That means the output I seek is :

```
CN = 
 [[1 2]
 [2 0]]
```

However, I tried some code like this:

```
result = np.array((Y == 1))
Y1 = Y[result]
Y1 = Y1.reshape(-1,1)
CN = np.where(Y1.dot(Y1.T) == np.square(Y1) , 1 , 2)
```

But I got:

```
CN = 
 [1]
```

not

```
CN = 
 [[1 2]
 [2 0]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you get from _'when Y value == 1'_ to output `CN = 
 [[1 2]
 [2 0]]`. I cannot find a logic with which you can get that output. Maybe you can explain each element of `CN` from `Y` so we can help better. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just solved it using this line: CN = np.where( np.logical_or(Y == 1, Y.T == 1), np.where(Y.dot(Y.T) == np.square(Y),1,2) , 0)